# Are there ANY "good guys" in the Mojave Wasteland?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm 100+ hours in to my first playthrough of Fallout: New Vegas, and I'm getting to the point where I will soon have to "make a choice" regarding the future of the Wasteland.

Until I met Yes-Man (I *so* need someone like him in the real world, preferably armed), I was ready to side with the NCR. Then as I progressed further, I found out some of the evil, rotten things they -- and the Crimson Caravan -- have done. Right now I'm strongly leaning toward an independent New Vegas.

Every faction (except, possibly, the Powder Gangers) seems to have both good and evil qualities to it. From the Brotherhood to the NCR, from the Legion to the Great Khans, from Mr. House to the families which actually run his casinos.

Nothing is cut-and-dried. I suppose I should expect this in a Fallout game, but this is a *lot* more gray area than Fallout 3 (my first introduction to the series) presented.

Are there any truly "good" guys, or is everything so gray that helping any given faction could be construed as good or evil?

Comment: One thing, Fallout: New Vegas is much more like the original Fallout games because it was actually made by the same developers. Or so I've heard.

Comment: @user56 No it wasn't.

Comment: @Selonianth Yes, yes it was. Obsidian Entertainment, who made New Vegas, includes among it's staff a *significant* number of people who worked on Fallout and Fallout 2, including, most notably, New Vegas's lead guy, J.E. Sawyer, who had been the lead dev for Black Isle's cancelled attempt at a Fallout 3, codenamed Van Beuren, from which much of New Vegas's setting was cribbed.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz No. It was not. New Vegas was developed primarily by Bethesda Softworks, the same people who made Fallout 3 and who still own the rights to Fallout. New Vegas was made in cooperation with them, but not BY them.

Comment: @Selonianth No. New Vegas was **Published** by Bethesda. It was **developed** by Obsidian, under a contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could maybe argue that the Followers of the Apocalypse are "Good Guys", but even they refuse to offer assistance to the Strip without some coercion.

As far as the four primary plot paths go though, no, there's no black and white to be had. All four players have redeeming qualities, and they've all done (varying amounts of) extremely questionable, if not outright irredeemable stuff.

In general, the moral choices in FO:NV are not about good or evil. They're about priorities and willingness to pay various prices - which makes for a much more interesting moral landscape.

Comment: I would argue that the Legion's few semi-redeemable actions are extremely outweighed by their innumerable cruel and inhumane ones.

Answer (score 1):

that question is extremely subjective as it would depend on who you ask. All of the factions believe that they are "good" (well, except maybe for the fiends).

Comment: The Fiends just need another fix maaaaaaan. If you get in their way, that's *your problem*.

Comment: maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan